# Update db on successful payment django

Tags: python, django, paypal

I have a model named 'Exhibition', where i enable users to create a new exhibition/event after filling out a form they are asked to pay some amount and are redirected to a payment gateway (paypal as per [django-paypal](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html)), after successful payment i want to update my 'Exhibition' table only for those who have paid, users are requested to login before creating an event and i am also saving the user with the form in my db.

This is my view for saving the form:

```
def new_event(request):
    form = NewEventForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.user = request.user
        save_it.save()

    return render_to_response('new_event.html',locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my model:

```
class Exhibition(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null = True)
    Type = models.ForeignKey('home.Type')
    Category = models.ForeignKey('home.Category')
    Country = models.ForeignKey('home.Country')
    City = models.ForeignKey('home.City')
    Event_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    Video_url = models.URLField(blank = True)
    Event_start_date = models.DateField(blank = False)
    Event_end_date = models.DateField(blank = False)
    Discription = RichTextField(blank = False)
    Contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank = True )
    Company = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank = True)
    Company_website = models.URLField(blank = True)
    Email  = models.EmailField(blank = True)
    Event_website = models.URLField(blank = True)
    Event_email = models.EmailField(blank = True)
    Venue = models.CharField(max_length = 250, blank = False)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length = 250, blank = False)
    Paid = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, default='0')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.Event_name

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_category', None, { 'slug': self.Event_name })
```

If i use django-paypal view, i would be able to process payment but i don't know how to get the correct 'Exhibition - id' to update the db, shall i store it in cookies and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding a post_save signal handler to django-paypal's model PayPalStandardBase and then use the transaction record's fields to identify your exhibition record. You could use the primary key field of your model and tell paypal that it is your item number for the transaction, or just add any other unique field you want to use as common identifier.

Check out the model here:

https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/standard/models.py

The signal handler would look like:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=PayPalStandardBase)
def mark_as_paid(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        e = Exhibition.objects.get(pk=instance.item_number)
        e.Paid = ...
        e.save()
```

You can add it to a models.py of yours or a signals.py which you then import elsewhere.

Comment: I am little bit confused, after successful payment user will be redirected to an another page, then how will i get item_number there? Do i have to store it in cookies?

Comment: No, a signal handler is not a view. A post_save handler gets triggered automatically when a transaction is saved. It doesn't matter what your view does.

Comment: i still have no idea how to do it. Can you please tell me how to do it completely in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a custom field containing the user id , and recover it when paypal notify you back.

See custom below : 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Comment: I know about IPN variables but i don't know how to use them in django, can you give me an example for the same, it would be great help. Thanks!

Comment: In the call back url recover the value from the request : request.POST['customvariablename']